# A photo of a WHAT on its cover

Tags: interrogatives, in-situ-wh-questions

Is this question grammatically correct?

> Published in 1936, the first issue of Life magazine had a Margaret Bourke-White photo of a what on its cover?

Can words like "the", "a", or a number be followed by the word "what"?

Comment: If the photo was of the four letters, "WHAT", it is acceptable to simply surround the word with quotes (... *photo of "WHAT"* ...). You can make it even clearer by calling it a photo of "the word 'WHAT'".

Comment: @Lawrence But that's a very unlikely reading of the sentence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible, but only as a kind of *artificial* question posed as if asked on a television game show.  A similar, but more common phrasing on these kind of programs would be:

> Q. Published in 1936, the cover of the first issue of Life Magazine featured a photo, taken by Margaret Bourke-White, of **what** (landmark)?
>
> A: The Fort Peck Dam.

Comment: In my opinion, that makes sense. So you are saying that questions used in quiz shows should be rephrased to make it more understandable and grammatically correct, right?

Comment: If you watch an English quiz show, while naturally the questions will be grammatically correct, the questions will generally end with the specifics of what they are asking.  This is also true for any games that ask questions, for example, "red, green, and white are the colors of the flags of **what nations**?"

Comment: Can the word "what" in my question posted act as a noun itself?

Comment: @AnisHaidarAli Yes, I think the "what" functions as a special kind of noun, but I'd have to look up what it is called.  I'm not an expert in linguistics and I don't know all the jargon.

Comment: I found the answer. The word "what" in my question posted acts as a placeholder, analogous to a blank space in a fill-in-the-blank question.